# unrecognized trace type "contour" plotly javascript

Tags: javascript, contour, plotly

The following code is not working. It is supposed to plot a "contour" plot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <!-- D3.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->   
  <script src="https://d14fo0winaifog.cloudfront.net/plotly-basic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>
  var size = 100, x = new Array(size), y = new Array(size), z = new Array(size), i, j;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    x[i] = y[i] = -2 * Math.PI + 4 * Math.PI * i / size;
    z[i] = new Array(size);
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        var r2 = x[i]*x[i] + y[j]*y[j];
        z[i][j] = Math.sin(x[i]) * Math.cos(y[j]) * Math.sin(r2) / Math.log(r2+1);
    }
}

var data = [ {
        z: z, 
        x: x, 
        y: y, 
        type: "contour"
    }
];

Plotly.plot("myDiv", data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following warning in the console:

unrecognized trace type "contour"

The code is the basic example provided on plotly website.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation `plotly-basic.js` is for basic charts. Contour charts are advanced charts - see https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/#advanced-charts

Comment: And do we have to pay for this? Does it exist a free library for contour plot?

Comment: Yes, you have to pay for it. If you are looking for recommendations you might want to head over to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Cheers!